# Error 1604 ..right syntax to use near '' at line

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure and for the life of me I do not understand why I get the above error. I tried moving the END // slashes closer and further away, I added a ; before the //
What am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ETL10501(TableStartPointer TIMESTAMP, TableWindowPointer TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE RowsExtractedCnt INT;
    DECLARE RowsExtractedMaxID INT;
    DECLARE RowsInsertedMaxID INT;
    DECLARE InsertedRowCount INT;
    DECLARE tmpTableWindowPointer TIMESTAMP;

    SELECT RowsExtractedCnt = COUNT(*), RowsExtractedMaxID = MAX(ID) FROM tbl10501Raw 
        WHERE tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime = tbl10501Raw.ReceivedAt 
        AND tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime BETWEEN TableWindowPointer AND TableStartPointer;

    SELECT RowsInsertedMaxID = (SELECT MAX(RowsExtractedMaxID10501) FROM etlETLEventLog);

    IF RowsExtractedMaxID IS NULL THEN SET RowsExtractedMaxID:=0;
    IF RowsInsertedMaxID  IS NULL THEN SET RowsInsertedMaxID:=0;

    IF RowsExtractedMaxID > RowsInsertedMaxID THEN
        SELECT tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime INTO tmpTableWindowPointer FROM tbl10501Raw 
            WHERE RowsInsertedMaxID = (tbl10501Raw.ID + 1);
        INSERT INTO tblLast7Days
            (CustomerID, DeviceID, Message, Facility, Severity, DeviceReportedTime, 
            InfoUnitID, SysLogTag)  
        SELECT tbl10501Raw.CustomerID, etlDIMDeviceNumbers.DeviceID, tbl10501Raw.Message, 
            tbl10501Raw.Facility, tbl10501Raw.Severity, tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime, 
            tbl10501Raw.InfoUnitID, tbl10501Raw.SyslogTag
        FROM etlDIMDeviceNumbers, tbl10501Raw
        WHERE tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime = tbl10501Raw.ReceivedAt
        AND tbl10501Raw.FromHostIP = etlDIMDeviceNumbers.DeviceIPAddress
        AND tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime BETWEEN tmpTableWindowPointer AND TableStartPointer;

        SELECT InsertedRowCount = COUNT(*) 
            FROM etlDIMDeviceNumbers, tbl10501Raw
            WHERE tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime = tbl10501Raw.ReceivedAt
            AND tbl10501Raw.FromHostIP = etlDIMDeviceNumbers.DeviceIPAddress
            AND tbl10501Raw.DeviceReportedTime BETWEEN tmpTableWindowPointer AND 
            TableStartPointer;

        UPDATE etlETLEventLog 
            SET RowsActualInserted10501 = InsertedRowCount, 
                RowsExtractedCnt10501 = RowsExtractedCnt, 
                RowsExtractedMaxID10501 = RowsExtractedMaxID
        WHERE etlETLEventLog.TableStartPointer = TableStartPointer;
    END IF;
END; // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for assisting and helping so promptly.

I found after many pages of searching that MySQL error 1604 is a syntax error. So I started removing code until I found the problem.

The two lines:

```
    IF RowsExtractedMaxID IS NULL THEN SET RowsExtractedMaxID:=0;
    IF RowsInsertedMaxID  IS NULL THEN SET RowsInsertedMaxID:=0;
```

somehow does not work syntactically. I honestly do not know why. I proceeded to include them into the main SELECT statements using the variables.

```
    SELECT IFNULL(RowsExtractedCnt = COUNT(*), 0), IFNULL(RowsExtractedMaxID = MAX(ID), 0)
            FROM tbl10760Raw 
            WHERE tbl10760Raw.DeviceReportedTime = tbl10760Raw.ReceivedAt 
            AND tbl10760Raw.DeviceReportedTime 
            BETWEEN TableWindowPointer AND TableStartPointer;

    SELECT IFNULL(RowsInsertedMaxID = (SELECT MAX(RowsExtractedMaxID10760) FROM etlETLEventLog), 0);
```

I hope this helps someone one day with a similar problem.